# Generate all Binary Search Trees from 1 to n, using dynamic programming

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

I am working on a practice problem for an exam, which is to write a program to generate all binary search trees that store values from 1...n.

We are supposed to use dynamic programming.

The accepted solution is

```
/**
 * Definition for binary tree
 * class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
public class Solution {

public ArrayList<TreeNode> helper(int m, int n){
    ArrayList<TreeNode> result = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();
    if(m>n){
        result.add(null);
        return result;
    }

    for(int i=m; i<=n; i++){
        ArrayList<TreeNode> ls = helper(m, i-1);
        ArrayList<TreeNode> rs = helper(i+1, n);
        for(TreeNode l: ls){
            for(TreeNode r: rs){
                TreeNode curr = new TreeNode(i);
                curr.left=l;
                curr.right=r;
                result.add(curr);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public ArrayList<TreeNode> generateTrees(int a) {
    if(a == 0){
        return new ArrayList<TreeNode>();
    }

    return helper(1, a);
}
```

However I don't understand how this is a dynamic programming solution and not just plain recursion. The results of helper arent being stored anywhere, so won't certain calculations be recomputed from scratch?

Comment: Just at first glance, I believe that the "dynamic programming" part of this is just expanding on each previous tree to get the next one without recomputing that part of the tree

Comment: As already pointed out, this is most likely considered as dynamic programming due to the fact that each problem is solved by solving smaller subproblems. On the other hand it entirely lacks memorization, so this is most definitely not DP in the common sense.